# Error in Custom Taxonomy UI

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Hi I'm running a site that makes heavy use of a custom taxonomy called 'Games' and using the Simple Term Meta plugin the metadata for these terms. Using pretty much a copy of the code from [wordheavy.com](http://wordheavy.com/blog/2010/08/10/using-term-meta/) it's working fine except for two things: it throws an error on the 'Game' taxonomy page (Warning: Missing argument 2 for game_form_fields() in **ommitted**/functions.php on line 32) and when you add a 'game' the form doesn't clear.

You can find a copy of my code [here](http://pastebin.com/57UHsikT).

I'm not quite where to start (apart from line 32!) so any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue at first glance appears to be here..

```
add_action('game_edit_form_fields', 'game_form_fields');
add_action('game_add_form_fields', 'game_form_fields');
function game_form_fields($tag,$taxonomy) {
```

Your function is expecting 2 vars to be passed from the hook, but your [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) calls default to 1..

Eg, this..

```
add_action('game_edit_form_fields', 'game_form_fields');
```

Is equal to this..

```
add_action('game_edit_form_fields', 'game_form_fields', 10, 1 );
```

The fourth parameters sets how many arguments your callback function can take, and the default is 1, so that's all your function ever receieves. Updating those [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) calls to the following should fix it..

```
add_action('game_edit_form_fields', 'game_form_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Hope that helps..

#### Follow-up #1

Maybe the hook isn't passing a second variable, instead of the previous change, try update the function line to read..

```
function game_form_fields( $tag ) {
```

Perhaps that will fix it..

Comment: Hey there,
That (rather unfortunately) doesn't seem to have made a difference :/

Comment: You're still seeing the message? Are you sure you saved the change? Can't see what else it could be, and that's the exact problem the error message relates to(i'm about 99.9% sure of that)..

Comment: Yep changes saved, same message, and cached cleared.

Comment: See update in answer.

Comment: Had the problem back to front, but solved it in the end... :)  You're welcome.. :)